# Quotient space if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $x \sim y$ iff $y=x +2\pi k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm having big troubles in my homework when I try to describe what is $X/\sim$,  if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $x \sim y$  iff $y=x +2\pi k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that the equivalence classes of $X$ are straight lines $y=x+2\pi k$. Also a hint is to consider the function $x\mapsto e^{ix}$. I know that the map $g(x)=e^{ix}$ is continuous and $Im(g)\subset \mathbb{C}$ is the unit circle. So is $X/\sim$ homeomorphic to the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$?

Can somebody give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight lines?  The equivalence classes look more like a discrete collection of points, each differing from the other by an integer multiple of $2π$.

Because of that, I think you essentially have an interval like $[0,2π]/\sim$, where $0\sim2π$.

Indeed it looks like a circle, topologically.

Comment: I have another question: Is $g$  a quotient map? Also Can I take $\pi$ as $g$?

Comment: I think so.  And yes, I think you can.  You need to be careful that the definitions are met.

Comment: Since $g$ is continuos and surjective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to the unit circle on $\mathbb{C}$ then $g$ is a quotient map.

Answer (score 3):

These equivalence classes are not supposed to be straight lines, but rather sets of points, in each set two subsequent points are separated by $2\pi$. Each point on the (unit) circle represents such an equivalence class. The mapping between the circle and the equivalence classes is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Your function $g$ has the property that $g(x)=g(x')$ iff $x \sim x'$.
This implies that $\bar{g}: X/{\sim} \to g[X]$ defined by $\bar{g}([x])=g(x)$ is well-defined (it does not matter which representative of the class of $x$, which I denote by $[x]$, we take to compute the image; all of them differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$ and so give the same $g$ value.
$\bar{g}$ is also 1-1 (if points/classes have the same image, they were some $2k\pi$ apart and from the same class, so in fact the same point in the quotient).
Surjectivity is also clear, by definition almost and so we check $\hat{g}$ is continuous: if $O \subseteq \Bbb C$ is open $\hat{g}^{-1}[O]$ is open iff $q^{-1}[\hat{g}^{-1}[O] = (\hat{g} \circ q)^{-1}[O] = g^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$ and this is indeed the case by continuity of $g$ from $X$ to $\Bbb C$. So $\hat{g}$ is a continuous bijection from $X/{\sim}$ to $S^1 = g[X]$ and it's easy to verify that we here have a homeomorphism.